# I want to convert 18-Aug-2015 date format to '2015-08-18' using shell script

Tags: shell, date, unix

I want to convert 18-Aug-2015 date format to '2015-08-18' using shell script

Comment: What is the input? A string?

Comment: input string is 18-Aug-2015 , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this formatting:

`$ date +"%Y-%m-%d"`

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/

Answer (score 0):

The -d option is GNU specific.

Here, you don't need to do date calculation, just rewrite the string which already contains all the information:

```
a=$(printf '%s\n' "$Prev_date" | awk '{
  printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", $6, \
  (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3,$3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `awk`, assuming your initial date is in `$mydate`:

```
IFS=- d=($mydate)
months=(Zer Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
z=1
while [[ ${months[$z]} != ${d[1]} ]]; do z=$((z+1)); done
printf "%s-%02d-%s\n" ${d[2]} $z ${d[0]}
```